# Reading Excel file using pandas

Tags: python

I am reading excel file with multiple sheets in pandas. It is creating OrderedDict for each sheet.How can I read the values and extract rows and columns data from it.

Comment: show your primary code

Comment: import pandas as pd
desired_tables = ['Table 7', 'Table 11', 'Table 12']
test_sheet = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Desktop\\TestReport.xlsx')

print(test_sheet.sheet_names)

for sheet in test_sheet.sheet_names:
    if sheet in desired_tables:
        df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\\Desktop\\TestReport.xlsx', header=[0],
                           sheet_name=[sheet], skiprows=2, nrows=5,usecols=['A', 'B', 'C', 'Power',  'Averaging Time (minutes)'],
                            encoding='utf-8')
        keys = df.keys()
        values = df.values()
        print(keys)
        print(values)